# How to get reference to GameObject without using Find() in C#/Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently taking an intro to games programming class and in the lecture notes it mentions that instead of using something like:

`GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("name");`

inside functions, you can "add object as Public member of type GameObject and connect it in the inspector" without actually explaining how to do it.

I tried to lookup how to do this but was unable to find how to properly do so, would appreciate any help.

Comment: @derHugo the code I showed is used inside methods, the code I WANT is used inside class. See answer below.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I should have seen that comma, my bad ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could do it. Lets say you want `obj2` in `obj1`

First go in the script of `obj1` and declare a `public` variable `public GameObject obj2;`

Then go in to the inspector of the `obj1`, on script component you will find a field `Obj2`. Now just drag and drop the `obj2` from hierarchy in that field or click a circular button next to field and select the object from the list.

Comment: In general all [serialized fields](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) are displayed in the Inspector and stored together with your scene or prefab asset. `public` fields are serialized automatically in c#. Private ones you can make by using the `[SerializeField]` attribute

Comment: What is meant by serialized in the scene is that if you marked a private/protected field with SerializedField attribute, the value in Inspector is saved and used. Else, the value in the script is used.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `public` access-modifier, or for fields with the `private`(default), `internal` or `protected` access-modifier, if you *annotate* with `[SerializeField]`, they will show up in the inspector, if they are *serializable* and of a supported type.

```
//This is shown in the inspector
public string _publicField = "public field";

//This is not shown in the inspector, unless you are in debug mode.
private string _privateField = "private field";

//This is shown in the inspector
[SerializeField]
private string _annotatedPrivateField = "annotated private field";
```

---

As for what the inspector is:

> The Inspector window (sometimes referred to as “the Inspector”)
>   displays detailed information about the currently selected GameObject,
>   including all attached components and their properties, and allows you
>   to modify the functionality of GameObjects in your Scene.

[image]

[From the official documentation.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingTheInspector.html)